# Problem on reading making a graph from a csv file. Won't read the header on the CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter, whitespace

I am new to Python and have been following this tutorial online that I found on solving the Chinese postman problem.

I've uploaded the CSV files that I needed, but whenever I am trying to define node positions data structure for plotting, it keeps saying '' KeyError: 'X' ''  which is one of the headers on my csv files

I've been told by a friend that  a possible problem could be that there were spaces in the CSV files, but I am unsure how to fix this as well.

I've tried using the files that was from the tutorial online and it was working fine so I am unsure of what I've done wrong.

```
ID, X, Y
'rep1', 1, 1811
etc..
```

is the kind of output I get when print(df) runs

I have also tried using delimeter but I may have been doing it wrong.

```
import itertools
import copy
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.read_csv("U:\directory\edge_list_3.csv")
df1=df1.dropna()
print(df1)

#add the r before the directory for it to be read
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"U:\\directory\nodes.csv")
df=df.dropna()
print(df)

##trial no 2, attempting to clear the white spaces
df=pd.read_csv(r'U:\\directory\nodes.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
data= pd.read_csv(r'U:\\directory\nodes.csv, error_bad_lines=False)
df=pd.read_csv(r'U:\\directory\nodes.csv', delimeter='  ')


#############################
#creating an empty graph 
g= nx.Graph()


df1_dict = df1.to_dict()

#display
df1_dict
###########Return the copied line here###
import networkx as nx
g=nx.Graph()


for i, elrow in df1.iterrows():

    g.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], **elrow[2:].to_dict())

print('\n')
    #edge list check
print(elrow[0])
print('\n')
print(elrow[1]) 

print(elrow[2:].to_dict())
################################
#node to a dict
df_dict=df.to_dict()

#Adding the node attributes

for i, nlrow in df.iterrows():
    nx.set_node_attributes(g, {nlrow['ID']: nlrow[1:].to_dict()})


    #Node list
    print(nlrow)


    #preview of the first  5 edges
list(g.edges(data=True))[0:5]

#same for nodes
list(g.nodes(data=True))[0:10]

print('no of edges: {}'.format(g.number_of_edges()))
print('no of nodes: {}'.format(g.number_of_nodes()))


#Problematic line
# Define node positions data structure (dict) for plotting
node_positions = {node[0]: (node[1]['X'], -node[1]['Y']) for node in g.nodes(data=True)}

  File "<ipython-input-22-3dbf80b62cb7>", line 19
    df=pd.read_csv(\\r'U:\\GE90\\nodes.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

# and if I take off the delimiter lines:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-38d6675d5393> in <module>
     79 
     80 # Define node positions data structure (dict) for plotting
---> 81 node_positions = {node[0]: (node[1]['X'], -node[1]['Y']) for node in g.nodes(data=True)}
     82 
     83 # Preview of node_positions .

<ipython-input-23-38d6675d5393> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     79 
     80 # Define node positions data structure (dict) for plotting
---> 81 node_positions = {node[0]: (node[1]['X'], -node[1]['Y']) for node in g.nodes(data=True)}
     82 
     83 # Preview of node_positions .

KeyError: 'X'

#this is what I got:
ID    rep1
```

X        1
Y     1811
Name: 0, dtype: object
ID    rep2
X        2
Y     1811
Name: 1, dtype: object
ID    rep4
X        4
Y     1135
Name: 2, dtype: object
ID    rep5
X        5
Y      420
Name: 3, dtype: object
ID    rep7
X        7
Y      885
Name: 4, dtype: object
ID    rep8
X        8
Y     1010
Name: 5, dtype: object
ID    rep10
X        10
Y      1010
Name: 6, dtype: object
ID    rep12
X        12
Y      1135
Name: 7, dtype: object
ID    rep13
X        13
Y      1135
Name: 8, dtype: object
ID    rep16
X        16
Y       885
Name: 9, dtype: object
ID    rep17
X        17
Y      1135
Name: 10, dtype: object
ID    rep19
X        19
Y      1000
Name: 11, dtype: object
ID    rep26
X        26
Y       850
Name: 12, dtype: object
ID    rep27 
X         27
Y        885
Name: 13, dtype: object
no of edges: 38
no of nodes: 16
        ID   X     Y
0     rep1   1  1811
1     rep2   2  1811
2     rep4   4  1135
3     rep5   5   420
4     rep7   7   885
5     rep8   8  1010
6    rep10  10  1010
7    rep12  12  1135
8    rep13  13  1135
9    rep16  16   885
10   rep17  17  1135
11   rep19  19  1000
12   rep26  26   850
13  rep27   27   885

---

Comment: You should specifiy your filennames like this: `df = pd.read_csv(r'U:\GE90\nodes.csv', delim_whitespace=True)`

Comment: Hi, I've tried it and this is the error I got :ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 15, saw 2

Comment: It would be super helpful to provide the first few lines or so of each of the files you are loading, so we can get a sense of what the "CSV" files actually look like.

Comment: Hi Merv, sorry about that, but I've added kind of a rough idea of what the values and headers are I hope that helps, but if there's anything else lacking please let me know

Comment: Hi Elizabeth DC, does your example file look exactly like you entered it? For a .csv file I would expect it to be structured differently...   <br/>
    ID, X, Y
    'rep1', 1, 1811
    'rep2', 2, 420
    ...

Comment: Can you provide the output of "df.head()' after you import the csv?

Comment: I couldn't upload an image of it for better understanding so I've just kind of entered it as that, sorry
--------

Comment: I've also added the ''df.head()'' line:

Comment: ......
rep19
{'X': 19, 'Y': 1000}
rep26
{'X': 26, 'Y': 850}
rep27
{}
 rep10
{}
rep27 
{'X': 27, 'Y': 885}  

I have noticed that near the end, there's rep10 and rep 26 without anything on it? could this be the cause of the problem? if so, what way could use to solve it?

Comment: If there are missing values in the input, that could cause your loop to have a key error. What is the output of `df.index` and `df.columns`?

Comment: Index(['ID', 'X', 'Y'], dtype='object')

Comment: I have also noticed that the size for the csv file doesn't show but the one for the edge_list shows the [181 rows x 6 columns]  after print(df)

Comment: Hey Elizabeth, I was on a small vacation and away from updates since last week. Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @mgrollins Hi! yes, I've managed to get this working. However, whenever I tried to make a new csv file similar to the one that works I keep getting the same error. So I just use the one that works as a template (I save as and change the values) to use ones that work

Comment: @mgrollins I have managed to get a solution to the chinese postman problem, but I need to further cut the solution, which means I need to somehow get the shortest paths answer and make another graph out of it just so people would understand it easier. Now I am trying to look into doing the Job shop scheduling problem just for the sequence of jobs for the 2 machines included in the sequence

Answer (score 0):

Does your example file look exactly like you entered it? For a .csv file I (and the Python csv library) would expect it to be structured more like this:

```
ID, X, Y
'rep1', 1, 1811
'rep2', 2, 420
etc....
```

This would explain why your key's were not as expected.

Comment: Hi, yes this is the output I get when I print(df). I couldn't insert an image of the actual table so I've kind of entered it as that. Sorry about that

Comment: Hi again, I have just noticed that the csv file where the X is connected to doesn't show the size? Whilst the 'edge_list' shows that [126 rows x 6 columns] size. I've tried to replace the node.csv file with another one and that one seems to work?

Comment: OK E, it sounds like you had a data quality issue in your 1st node.csv file. Good luck with the real part of your problem now that you've gotten past this! :-)

Comment: Would I just need to start fresh with this file for a fix?

Comment: Hmm, to really nail down why you got the error, I would suggest opening your original CSV file in a code editor and just scan all the rows by eye. Hopefully you'll be able to quickly see if there is obvious missing data. For an even quicker check for missing values, check that `df.isnull().values.any()` is False to verify there is no missing data before using it on your graph algo. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've written the csv file from excel and converted it at the save as stage to csv, could this have affected this?. And also, if I were to use the check (df.isnull().values.any() ) would I just set that equal to false? My apologies for this as I am still trying to get my head around this. This is all deep end work for someone who's just started beginner stuff not too long ago.

Comment: Writing from excel to CSV should work ok. I'm pretty new to Pandas as well and it get's confusing very quickly since each command is so powerful and does so many different things.  For the check, you want to print out the value of the `df.isnull().values.any()`, or have it in an if statement that if true, quit from your script with an error message. Upload your csv file to a google sheet or something and post a link, and I'll take a look!

Comment: It's quite a small spreadsheet so I'm a bit unsure as to where the problem likes. I've tried deleting extra spaces in Notepad++ but that doesn't seem to do the trick
but here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hp-dYICff7czX5DPVm_PoQB0D7A1SIDv9lJsJxKwnZQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, I've just tried printing print(df1.isnull().values.any()) and it came out False

Comment: I've tried making it out of notepad++ as a text file now and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Could I possibly ask for an alternative, such as maybe importing it from github as I've seen the example do it? how would I do so?